# Errors are generated when SAPI is run in QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt, text-to-speech, sapi

Here is my code:

```
#include <sapi.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ISpVoice * pVoice = NULL;

    if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
        return FALSE;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice;);
    if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        hr = pVoice->Speak(L"Hello world", 0, NULL);
        pVoice->Release();
        pVoice = NULL;
    }

    ::CoUninitialize();
    return TRUE;
}
```

This is my very first SAPI 5.1 Run, and this is the sample hello world provided by MS.

I have added the SAPI "bin" location to the system variable "Path".

Following is my QT project contect (.pro content)

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-04-26T12:59:05
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = Tired
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    ContentDetector.cpp \
    Speech.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/build/include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/build/include/opencv
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/win32"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Speech SDK 5.1/Include"

LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_calib3d240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_contrib240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_core240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_features2d240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_flann240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_highgui240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_imgproc240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_objdetect240.lib
LIBS += C:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_video240.lib
LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/lib/jvm.lib"
LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/lib/jawt.lib"
LIBS += "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Speech SDK 5.1/Lib/i386/sapi.lib"
```

Please note that SAPI include in the last include and SAPI lib is the last lib.

When I run this code, the followng error is generated.

```
C:\Users\yohan\Documents\QTPeojects\Tired\Speech.cpp:10: error: C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
C:\Users\yohan\Documents\QTPeojects\Tired\Speech.cpp:10: error: C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

I do not understand why.

### Update

The above error is now gone after following the instructions from John. But, now the below errors are generated. Why is that?

```
Speech.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CoUninitialize@0 referenced in function _main

Speech.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CoCreateInstance@20 referenced in function _main

Speech.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CoInitialize@4 referenced in function _main

release\Tired.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way was adding the ATL.

```
  #define _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED

#include <atlbase.h>
//You may derive a class from CComModule and use it if you want to override something,
//but do not change the name of _Module
extern CComModule _Module;
#include <atlcom.h>

#include <sapi.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    ISpVoice * pVoice = NULL;

    if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
        return FALSE;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
    if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        cout << "Succeeded" << endl;
        hr = pVoice->Speak(L"Hello world", 0, NULL);
        pVoice->Release();
        pVoice = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not succeeded" << endl;
    }

    ::CoUninitialize();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I tried to run the above code with mingw compiler, but I get error saying no include found for atlbase.h and atlcom.h. without this, the code compiles but on executing no sound is coming. Please help.

Comment: @programmer: my advice is not to use SAPI. Use MS speech API C# version. SAPI is having millions of troubles..

Comment: that's the problem. I need window's mingw verison and my project requirements is to use C++. Do you recommend any other speech api (other than MS) which I can build using mingw? Would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: @programmer: Can you use C++/CLI? I t will allow you to use both C#.Net and C++. `pocketsphinx` is a good API too. You can use `VOCE`as well -http://voce.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice;);
```

should be

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
```

There's an extra semi-colon in your version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. After following your instructions, that error is gone but new errors came in. Please have a look at the updated code

Comment: Those are linker errors because you aren't linking with the correct *import library*. This is a different kind of question from before and I'm not sufficiently familiar with Windows programming to be confident about the answer. So if you can't figure it out yourself then I would ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

the missing functions are in *user32.lib* ( but no idea how to add  that to your qt proj )

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunatly, it did not solve the issue :9

Answer (score 0):

Your linker problems stem from the fact that you're not referencing the libraries properly in the Qt .pro file.

To add a library you'd need to do something like this: -

LIBS += -LC:/opencv/build/x86/vc9/lib/ -lopencv_calib3d240

Note the -L before the path and the -l before the name of the library.